# Facing problem in sending form data on the server

Tags: angular, angular6, angular5, angular-httpclient, angular-http

- I am working on angular
- where I am trying to send File along with Data via Form Data
- but when I send my form data to the server , It is sending **null**

**Let me share my code**

**component.ts file**

```
  const token  = localStorage.getItem('currentUser');
  const formData  = new FormData();

  formData.append('proposal_details' , this.PackageDetails.get('proposal_details').value);
  formData.append('businessName' , this.PackageDetails.get('BusinessName').value);

  formData.append('package_type_id' ,   this.PackageArray),
  formData.append('package_list_id',this.PacageListArray),
  formData.append('budget',this.customPayArr),
  formData.append('is_manual',this.CheckAutoPayArr),
  // tslint:disable-next-line:max-line-length
  formData.append('full_package',this.PackageDetails.get('totalPackageFee_cur').value + ' ' + this.PackageDetails.get('totalPackageFee').value),
  formData.append('signUpAmount',this.PackageDetails.get('signUpAmount_cur').value + ' ' + this.PackageDetails.get('signUpAmount').value),
  formData.append('StartDate',this.PackageDetails.get('StartDate').value),
  formData.append('endDate' , ProjectendDate),
  formData.append('project_hours', this.PackageDetails.get('project_hours').value),
  formData.append('technology_used', this.PackageDetails.get('technology_used').value),
  formData.append('attach_file', this.PackageDetails.get('attach_file').value)

  console.log(formData);

  this.rest.newProposals(formData , token).subscribe(result => {
    console.log(result);
  });
```

**Servie.ts file**

```
 newProposals(value : FormData , token) {
   value.forEach(value => console.log(value));
   let headers = new HttpHeaders();
   headers = headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
   headers = headers.append('Authorization', token);
   return this.http.post<any>(this.addProposals , value , {headers});
  }
```

**

> Problem is >>

**

> My **form data is going Null on the server** which I am tying to send through post methord

Comment: what is FormData?

Answer (score 0):

You can not directly print FormData to console.log(), You need to use methods of formdata like get(), getAll()... for your use-case you can use .forEach() array method to traverse all value and get data to print in console.log. Complete working example can be found here..[StackBlitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ubauru)

here is your implementation..

```
const formData  = new FormData();

formData.append('proposal_details' , 'proposal_details');
formData.append('businessName' ,'BusinessName');

console.log(formData.getAll('businessName')); // using .getAll() method.

formData.forEach(data =>{ // using forEach array method.
    console.log(data); // logs data here.
})
```

Answer (score 0):

change the content-type from

`headers = headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');`
to
`headers = headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');`
in service file

corrected **Service.ts** File

```
 newProposals(value , token) {
       let headers = new HttpHeaders();
       headers = headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
       headers = headers.append('Authorization', token);
       return this.http.post<any>(this.addProposals , value , {headers});
      }
```